# Spring Vault AWS STS Assume Role support

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-vault

We are currently using Vault to generate temporary security credentials for AWS using STS. This is done by using the aws/sts backend within vault. To use this backend we need to POST (write) to this vault path, which will immediately generate a temporary set of credentials in AWS, that are then used to perform some action in AWS. These temporary credentials have a short TTL, as you would expect.

I was initially hoping that I could use the @VaultPropertySource to read this information from vault, but it looks like it only reads the values (GET), and doesn't try the POST to create the credentials first.

Is there some other method that I can use to achieve this, i.e. before retrieving the properties from the vault path, first create them using POST, and also handle the renewing of the token once the TTL has expired.

We are using spring vault 1.1.1.RELEASE currently

Thanks

Darrell

Answer (score 0):

It looks like vault will generate an AWS STS token on a read as well as a POST, so using the @VaultPropertySource will work as I had hoped.